# Need to convert a video file from mp4 to xvid

Tags: mp4, openshot, video-conversion

I checked out the questions with similar titles and didn't find anything that I thought would help.  I am attempting to convert a video into an avi, preferably xvid.  The video file's Video and Audio Properties are as follows:

```
Video
Dimensions: 1280x544
Codec H.264/AVC
Framerate: 24 frames per second
Bitrate: 774 kpbs

Audio
Codec: MPEG-4 AAC audio
Channels: Stereo
Sample Rate: 48000 Hz
Bitrate: 32 kpbs
```

I have tried numerous times to convert this into an Xvid codec AVI but I have had no luck successfully getting the audio to sync properly. I am using Openshot to attempt conversion, using the libxvid codec and AVI format, but I am unsure of the proper audio settings I should use. What settings should I use to convert this video with Openshot?  If it is not possible with Openshot, or if there is a better application to use, I would be grateful to know that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll close this one out with my own answer... after trying all of the suggestions and not getting anything close to a satisfactory conversion, I wound up using Format Factory in Window$ to get it done. Makes me sad.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the final 'answer' to your question? Might be a better idea to just keep the question unanswered, so people are still encouraged to find _Ubuntu_ answers to your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for conversion, you might want to try `arista` or `transmageddon` instead of Openshot. Arista Transcoder and Transmageddon are applications focused on just doing the conversion and nothing else. Especially Arista Transcoder contains a lot of presets, of which one is xvid. Install them using the command `sudo apt-get install arista transmageddon`.

Comment: OK I will try Arista and then Transmageddon, what are the best Audio settings to get the audio synced properly?

Comment: Well, Transmageddon converted the video, but it messed up the audio pretty badly.  I will try Arista and WinFF to see if either of those will work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using **WinFF** not because it's simple to use and it actually works, but because it dumps execution commands into *.sh files which are located in your **~/.winff/** directory. You can examine them and change parameters as you wish.

I had to convert some **mp4** videos from my **Samsung Galaxy** 2 to **avi XViD** format, and here's the command I came to thru the way I described earlier. Check this out if this works for you, if not, please try the Step 1, and post your command.

In my case I'm using **ffmpeg**, so here's the command (original, slightly modified for HDMI format output):

```
ffmpeg -y -i yourvid.mp4 -f avi -r 29.97 \
          -vcodec libxvid -vtag XVID \
          -vf scale=1920:1080 -b 1500k -qmin 3 -qmax 8 -bufsize 4096 \
          -mbd 2 -bf 2 -trellis 1 -flags +aic -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 300 \
          -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 \
          yourvid.avi
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try [avidemux](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/avidemux) [image: Install avidemux]. It works quite well.